# Implement Locks in Java using builtin semaphores

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore, java-threads, locks

I creating 5 threads and all access the critical section and read a value from file and change the value. However in the end all print the same value, that is the first value. How can I implement a lock using semaphores so that only one thread access the critical section at a time?

```
    public static class myThread extends Thread{
    int x;
    public myThread(int x){
        this.x = x;
    }
    private static final int MAX_AVAILABLE = 1;
    private final Semaphore available = new Semaphore(MAX_AVAILABLE, true);
    public void run(){         
            try{
                available.acquire();
                //Critical Section
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("Error");
            }
            finally{
                available.release();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: the problem here that every thread has its own semaphore (ie you have 5 different semaphores), but you need only one, make it static for example

Comment: Um you can't really protect a global resource (like a file) by allocated one lock per thread.  It doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for your responses  ...Making a static semaphore as a global variable works

Comment: Or better, implement `Runnable` instead of extending `Thread`. That's the preferred idiom anyhow, unless you really are creating a new kind of `Thread`. Not only are you not creating a new kind of `Thread` here, you want to share instance data in your runnable object! So implement `Runnable`!